# Arduino Uno board heating up and code not uploading

Tags: arduino

This is the  for the second time I'm facing this issue and seems to me that this frigging thing is not worth using. The board is heating up,  (the little chip in the vicinity of fdti port ) is becoming hot as hell.

None of the single snippets of  code is uploading to Arduino I'm getting that old lifelong persisting  error  (whenever I'm up on something this frigging errors comes into picture and destroys my work )

THE AVRDUDE ERROR.

I think I have screwed up just before new year.
Is there any way , I can turn this upside down?
And yeah I have burnt my fingers too.

Comment: Proper care and feeding is necessary for prolonged life. Knowing what "proper" amounts to needs to be learned with care - both from manuals and competent experienced users. 
Odds are it's dead, alas. Odds are you did something fatally wrong - which is somewhat easy. A number of the pins connect to the internals directly and must be treated as per device spec sheet. The power supply must be within the limits specified. Anti electrostatic discharge precautions must be taken when handling the device.

Comment: Is there a question here? All I see is a frustrated rant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper care and feeding is necessary for prolonged life.
Knowing what "proper" amounts to needs to be learned with care - both from manuals and competent experienced users. If two sets of users differ on their "what you can safely do" advice, err on the side of caution. There are many inexperienced users in this community - which is good, because the devices are targeted at being usable by the uninitiated - but which is also bad because much advice given may be suspect.

Odds are it's dead, alas.
Odds are you did something fatally wrong - which is somewhat easy.
A few non-exhaustive pointers:

- A number of the pins connect to the internals directly and must be treated as per device  spec sheet.
- The power supply must be within the limits specified.
- Anti electrostatic discharge precautions must be taken when handling the device.

Do check your power supply voltage.
Do check that you are connecting power to where it should be connected
(which is less silly than it may sound).

Answer (score 0):

> **The board is heating up, specially the flash memory chip**

AFAIK the [Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) doesn't have a flash memory chip.

The chip next to the USB port is an Atmega16U2 microcontroller which does the USB to serial conversions for which previous models of Arduino used an FTDI chip.

[image]

If you were using the ICSP header to program the Arduino you could connect it the wrong way around to the wrong ICSP header. However, whilst not good ™, it isn't obvious to me that this would fry the 16U2.

[PIGHIXX](http://www.pighixxx.com/) has created a useful diagram to show what connects where

[image]
<sup>*click to open full-sized*</sup>

> **in the vicinity of fdti port**

I think you mean [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/). There isn't an "FTDI port". Maybe you have connected an [FTDI USB to serial cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9717) to some inappropriate place?